# Schema for forum that displays last subject and user in the list of forums

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple forum as part of a larger project and one of the requirements is in the list of boards, we display the most recent topic along with the user who posted the topic.

Here are the relevant models I have:

```
Board
  name
  description
  subjects_count
  has_many Subjects

Subject
  title
  content
  user_id
  replies_count
  belongs_to Board
  belongs_to User
  has_many Replies

Reply
  content
  belongs_to Subject
  belongs_to User

User
  name
  has_many Subjects
  has_many Replies
```

On the boards index view, I have the following fields displayed for each active board (there will probably be 5-10 boards):

```
board.name
board.description
subjects_count
most_recent_subject_title
most_recent_subject_id
most_recent_subject_user_name
```

To display this information, right now, I'm using the method below:

```
 def get_boards_and_latest_subject
    Board.connection.select_all("SELECT boards.id, boards.name, boards.description, subjects.id as most_recent_subject_id, subjects.title as most_recent_subject_title, subjects.user_id, subjects.created_at, users.name as most_recent_subject_user_name, users.id as user_id, (select count(id) FROM subjects where board_id = boards.id) as subject_count
                                 FROM boards
                                 INNER JOIN (SELECT board_id, MAX(created_at) MaxDate FROM subjects s GROUP BY board_id) MAXDATES
                                 ON boards.id = MaxDates.board_id
                                 INNER JOIN subjects ON MaxDates.board_id = subjects.board_id AND MaxDates.MaxDate = subjects.created_at
                                 JOIN users ON subjects.user_id = users.id")
  end
```

I brought this SQL over from the platform I used to begin this project - CodeIgniter - but it seems a bit ridiculous to me now. The goal at the time was to reduce the number of queries when listing the boards.

Given the number of boards I have (5-10) wouldn't it be better to do something more like bringing back all the boards in a nice AR call and for each, getting the latest subject and user?

Or, another option would be to store the latest subject in the boards table - like a counter cache. Since I'm already updating the table when I add a subject - due to the counter cache, would it just be wise to update the last subject info as well?

The boards page on the site that exists today, which we're rebuilding, averages around 20K pageviews per month - so not huge traffic.